# Match character sequence in two strings

Tags: r, string, character, match, subsequence

I have the following problem:

```
a <- "blablabla_string_to_extract_qwertz"
b <- "werwer_qweqweq_string_to_extract_nnmn"
d <- c("hello", "This is nonsense", b)
```

Now I like to test in vector d, whether there is an entry that contains a sequence of characters that matche with a.
The output should be

> "werwer_qweqweq_string_to_extract_nnmn"

, because "string_to_extract" is part of a and also part of b. grep or grepl would not offer this, because the complete string must be found in d.

Another thing: I don't know that the string sequence "string_to_extract" I am looking for always starts and ends with "_", maybe it's directly connected to any other letter.

Thank you very much!

Comment: If your string always starts and ends with a `_` can't you just extract it and look for it? e.g. `grep(sub(".*?_(.*)_.*", "\\1", a), d, value = TRUE)`?

Comment: No, I said: I don't know that it always starts and ends like that. But the solution below is exactly that what I have been looking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
d[max.col(-adist(a,d,partial=T))]
[1] "werwer_qweqweq_string_to_extract_nnmn"
```

or you can use `agrep`

```
agrep(a,d,0.5,value = T)
[1] "werwer_qweqweq_string_to_extract_nnmn"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it.